# How to filter an array with a worksheet function?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm looking for a way to filter an array with an evaluated expression such as:

```
Dim arr1(), arr2(), arr3()

arr1 = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)           ' > [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

arr2 = Map(arr1, "Values() * 2")      ' > [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]

arr3 = Filter(arr2, "Values() > 6")   ' > [8, 10]
```

I've already implemented the `Map` function with an UDF and with  `Application.Evaluate("INDEX(expression, )")`, but I'm struggling to make it work for `Filter`:

```
Private arr_()

Public Function Values() As Variant()
  Values = arr_
End Function

Public Function Map(arr(), expression As String) As Variant()
  arr_ = arr
  Map = Application.Evaluate("INDEX(" & expression & ",)")
End Function

Public Function Filter(arr(), expression As String) As Variant()
  arr_ = arr
  Filter = Application.Evaluate("INDEX(Values(), " & expression & ")")
End Function
```

Is there a way other than looping/shifting each value? Maby with `VLOOKUP`?

Comment: I think you'll need to use a loop.

Comment: What Excel are you using?  There is a way if you are using Office 365 Excel with TEXTJOIN.  Otherwise it is down to iterating.  INDEX will return an array the same size as the input, they will be filled with `FALSE` and the numbers that resolve to TRUE.

Answer (score 1):

Although I am a big fan of arrays and delegating the most of the work to Excel's built-ins, for this one I found that the most appropriate is to do the main job in VBA, using Excel to `Evaluate` the expression for individual items.

```
Public Function FilterArr(arr(), expression As String)
  Dim match As Boolean, i As Long, val
  ReDim ret(LBound(arr) To UBound(arr))
  i = LBound(arr) - 1
  On Error Resume Next
  For Each val In arr
    match = False
    match = Application.Evaluate(val & expression)
    If match Then
      i = i + 1
      ret(i) = val
    End If
  Next
  If i >= LBound(arr) Then
    ReDim Preserve ret(LBound(arr) To i)
    FilterArr = ret
  End If
End Function
```

---

```
Sub test()
  Dim arr1(), arr2(), arr3()
  arr1 = Array(10, 20, 30, 40, 50)
  arr3 = FilterArr(arr1, ">25")   ' <--- usage like this
  ' arr3 = (30, 40, 50)
End Sub
```

p.s. an interesting extension would be to permit multiple criteria (i.e. `AND`ed together) using a `ParamArray`. Good candidate for future work...

Comment: As mentioned in the post I'm looking for a worksheet function and not a loop. The idea is to call `Application.Evaluate` only once to keep the performance decent and to allow a 2d/1d array as input.

Comment: @michael There's a fundamental flaw in what you're saying. **How do you filter a 2D array?** Usually you specify a column and remove or hide entire rows. Your "Filter" examines all the entries, so what to do when an emtry doesn't match, remove the row? the column? To see the flaw, `Delete` a single cell in Excel and read carefully the question it prompts you.

Comment: It seems that you've answered your own question: "Usually you specify a column and remove or hide entire rows.". You are simply missing the usage where the values are from a single range/column: `Filter([A1:A100].Value, "Values() > 100")`.

Comment: There's no mention about it in your post.

Comment: Whether it's a 1d or 2d array is irrelevant here since it is handled the same way with a worksheet function.

Answer (score 1):

First change the function to the following...

```
Public Function Filter(arr(), sValues As String, sCriteria As String) As Variant()
  Dim Cnt As Long
  arr_ = arr
  Cnt = Application.Evaluate("SUMPRODUCT(--(" & sValues & sCriteria & "))")
  If Cnt > 0 Then
    Filter = Application.Evaluate("TRANSPOSE(INDEX(SMALL(IF(" & sValues & sCriteria & "," & _
        sValues & "),ROW(INDEX(A:A,1):INDEX(A:A," & Cnt & "))),0))")
  Else
    Filter = Array()
  End If
End Function
```

Then call it like this...

```
arr3 = Filter(arr2, "Values()", ">6")
```

Comment: Thanks, this works with my example but `SMALL` is way too expensive (more than 20 seconds for 10k rows) and it doesn't work with a string evaluation (ex:  = "a").

Comment: Yeah, I hadn't tested it with that many rows, but I expected it to be rather expensive.  And, while it can be amended to deal with string evaluations, I guess there's no use in doing so, since it's not going to be practical.

Comment: Yes, it wouldn't be practical. I was hoping to use `INDEX` with an incremented row based on the result of the evaluation, but it doesn't seem possible with a function. Looks like I'll have to keep using a loop.